# How to search the changed fields in TFS History?

Tags: search, tfs, history

I am working with TFS 2010. I need to find a way to search the fields that have changed which are tracked in the history of a work item. As fields are changed and updated they get tracked in History and you can view them by opening the "Show Changes(Fields)" dropdown. Is there a way to search this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function for that however I needed the same thing some time ago and I wrote a little utility called **TFS Helper** that does it (and some more things).

You can get the source code from **codeplex**. The tab named "Work Item Field History" is what you want. It shows changed fields of a work item with the number of changes. You can see all changes when you click on a field.

http://tfshelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks e-mre. I will have to have our IT guy check this out.